# Android Upload Image Progress Bar

Tags: java, android, percentage, progress

I am trying to find a way to show the uploading file's progress in Progress Bar and percentage. I need to add a progress bar and transfer percentage of the file.

Here's my code. It's transferring file but has no progress bar.

```
package com.example.christian.progressbar5;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView ivImage;
    Button btnUpload;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    EditText etFilename;
    final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 38473;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etFilename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFilename);
        ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


        ivImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }
        });

        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                uploadImage();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if(requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST){
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                    ivImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void uploadImage()
    {
        final String filename = etFilename.getText().toString();
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        String URL = "http://inventsystem.esy.es/uploadimage2.php";
        Bitmap resized = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 500);
        final String photo = ImageToString(resized);

        if(bitmap == null || bitmap.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if(filename.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "What's the filename?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image has been Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("image", photo);
                params.put("name", filename);
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private String ImageToString(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteArray);
        byte[] imgBytes = byteArray.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(imgBytes,Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        float bitmapRatio = (float)width / (float) height;
        if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
            width = maxSize;
            height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
        } else {
            height = maxSize;
            width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
        }
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this http://suyu-android-dev.blogspot.in/2012/09/display-percentage-on-progressbar.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use VolleyPlus instead of Volley to add this feature.

```
jsonRequest.setOnProgressListener(new Response.ProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(long transferredBytes, long totalSize) {
                int percentage = (int) ((transferredBytes / ((float) totalSize)) * 100);

            }
        });
```

There's a nice code snipplet how to do it here:
https://github.com/DWorkS/VolleyPlus/issues/53

Comment: Hi, Where do I apply that code sir? Volley Plus is doing well.. but I'm afraid I don't know where to put the jsonRequest.setOnProgressListener.. Pls give a hint. Thanks, Hristo!

Comment: You should put it between the StringRequest constructor and adding it to the que. (right before this: queue.add(stringRequest))